# When I finish drawing a polygon, it disappears again (although appearing in my attribute table)

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing

I'm working with Quantum GIS at this moment. And as the title says, when I finish drawing a polygon, it disappears again. The new object does appear in my attribute table and in the legend/'filling of the polygon' should not be the problem. Before this never happend, so I supposed it was some change I made in the options. But even after reinstalling the program the problem stays. 
After searching for a while I discovered that on a new project it works correctly till the moment I import a vector-file I made before with line objects.
How can importing a file have such an influence?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Settings -> Options -> Digitizing -> On 'Suppress attributes pop-up windows after each created feature' - in this issue?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I think that is not the problem. I can add atributes to the created polygon, it is visible in my attribute list, but the polygon is not visible. The other polygons of the same layer are.

Comment: Is your Layer using categorized style or rule-based symbols? If it is, and you are not giving one of the classified Values to your polygon, it won't be visible in the map as it has no symbol to draw. If that is the case, just reclassify the style, or add the new Value.

Comment: I tried categorized style by adding categories, using existing categories and also using the only-symbol function. It seems something else is going on, because I can make polygons, till the moment I add an existing vectorfile (consisting of lines in this case).

Comment: Sorry to ask obvious questions, but, did you try to open the shapefile in another other project? Does the Layer have any query? Can you send the file so we can check it? BTW what Qgis version are you using?

Comment: Just ask questions, maybe I forgot to check some small thing. Well, I keep on trying different things and it's still not clear what is exactly the problem. I tried several times to open a new project and sometimes I have the same problem, other times not. So I can't give too much information for now. I am not using any queries till now and I use QGIS 1.8.0

Comment: is the shapefile in a different coordinate system than the project?

Comment: The project and all the file use the same coordinate system.. I was hoping so hard that that was the problem, but no. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi, after trying several times to open a new project and import the files I made before, I manage to draw polygons and continued my work. Till this morning I started QGIS and my line-file does not show the lines anymore on my map. This program is doing strange things or something is wrong with my computer.

Comment: I kept on working, but the probleem still shows up. I discovered that it indeed is a problem in the reference system. Although my layer and project, for both I chose the same CRS. But the objects are put on coordinate 0,0 and also invisible. If afterwards I try to safe the layer QGIS collapses :( Does anybody experienced the same?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and no way to fix it yet :( I've made tests and it seems like it disappear whenever is close to another polygon. But it doesn't make sense 'cause other adjacent polygons are ok.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured this out.  My project included tracing multiple river islands and sandbars, and 9/10 times my painstaking sketches disappeared using the auto-complete freehand or polygon tools.  I noticed that the 1 polygon out of 10 that was created was a bit messy, i.e. the last line or point crossed the initial line or point where I started the shape.  It seems in order to complete a polygon using these toos, your finishing line has to cross over a portion of where you started.  Then hit F2 or right click and click "Finish Sketch."  Works fine now.  Good luck!

(see image below)

[image]