# Why do my added features vanish?

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS 2.12.1-Lyon on OSX Yosemite, I am following [this tutorial](http://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?t=17469).

I cannot add any polygon on the map : I can draw the polygon, but as soon as I right-click, the polygon disepear, even if the *Features Attributes* windows is prompted.

**Editing the feature** (Polygon is stretched in order to reach the screenshot tool)
[image]

**After right-clicking**
[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug ?

Comment: Did you click ok?

Comment: Yes, obviously, and I enter a name. But the polygon disappears once I right click to finish the creation. And giving a name and clicking ok does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that your Countries layer has a categorized renderer applied - judging by the 'expand arrow' next to the layer name.

So - when you're adding a feature, though you are adding geometry, you need to give it a name that has a value in the category you're renderer is based on.

Since you haven't added any values at all, the polygon won't have a symbol in the renderer, and hence it won't show up until you add a name (again, depending on what field is being used to symbolize the Countries layer).

Comment: @JeanRene great! I hope it works!!! (might want to point out that error to the creators of the tutorial, just in case others are having that issue!)

Answer (score 1):

[You could be not completing the polygon completely.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35514/when-i-finish-drawing-a-polygon-it-disappears-again-although-appearing-in-my-a) If you are drawing features at the zoom level that you have in your screen shot, it's very possible that you are not actually finishing the polygon (at this level you can be 100s of feet off and it looks like you are right on top of the starting point.

Or [It could be possible that when you are creating your polygon, it is saving at the origin.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62165/why-new-feature-disappears-when-editing-polygon) Open your attribute table to see if the data actually saved or not.

If you could update your question to let us know if 1) your zoom level when you are sketching and 2) if the drawings appear in your attribute table, it would be helpful.