# New Polygons vanish when ID is added

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers

I am working on an old QGIS project and want to add new polygons to a layer. I have the data for the polygon in the attribute file showing an ID no and other data which also relates to other existing polygon in the layer . When I draw the polygon it is visible but when the data window opens and I add the ID and hit return the polygon vanishes
QGIS 3.22.11 on Windows 10.
Information from provider

Storage GPKG
Encoding UTF-8
Geometry Polygon (MultiPolygon)
Extent
634274.5000000000000000,298778.2187500000000000 : 637503.5625000000000000,300672.9062500000000000
Feature count 209

Coordinate Reference System (CRS) Name EPSG:27700 - OSGB36 / British National Grid
Units meters
Method Transverse Mercator
Celestial body
Earth
Reference Static (relies on a datum which is plate-fixed)

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing a screenshot. As a guess - it may be a symbology issue. If you have a categorised or rule-based symbology that does not cater for "other values" then the polygon will not be symbolised until you enter an attribute value in the field used for categorising. Or it could be something as simple as accidentally having your polygon layer beneath a basemap layer in the layers panel.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. The symbology is categorized and the attribute table has all the info need. There is also other values the polygon layer is above the base map. When I enter the id no and the polygon vanished the ID is added to the attribute table. I have a screenshot but cant see how to attach it!!

Comment: You can paste a screenshot from your clipboard, or drag the file and drop it into the editable part of the question body. If successful you will see a dialogue appear asking to confirm adding a picture.

Comment: Hi Checked what you said again and yes there was no "Other Values"!!!!!! Thanks for your help much appreciated

Comment: Before posting a Question, please be sure to search on the title you chose. There are several posts on features which "vanish", with this one on QGIS: [Why do my added features vanish?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174117/why-do-my-added-features-vanish)